# Spring boot console exception after hitting request on postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am hitting a request whose response is 500 Internal Server Error.
I am getting spring boot exception in console as below. I am posting few starting lines of exception as stackoverflow has restrictions on number of words. I am using spring security in my project for authorization of apis. Is the issue related to version of spring boot and version of spring security dependency in pom.xml ? Thanks for suggestions in advance.

```
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:514) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
```

Below is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>policymanagementsystem</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>policymanagementsystem</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
  <!--<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version> 
</dependency> --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.passay</groupId>
       <artifactId>passay</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>5.4.2.Final</version> -->
        </dependency>
        
   <!--  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.2</version> 
    </dependency>  -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>5.4.2.Final</version> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version> -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.22</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
         </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: can you share a more complete stacktrace that contains a reason and type for the exception you get? Spring exceptions are usually very long, the last or second to last "caused by" is usually the one that caused the issue.

Comment: last 5 lines of exception:

```at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:514) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_333]```

Comment: I am extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter which is showing as deprecated in my spring boot

Comment: Not the `at ...` part, where it says `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext` .. `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'datasource'` ... That's the relevant part that tells you what the type and reason of error is. You can edit your question, comments aren't a good place for additional information to your question.

Comment: @zapl I got your point. That's where I am confused at, I am not getting any exception. Just a whole bunch of console starting with at.
It seems my spring boot version and spring security version is not compatible. Is it that?
Do you have info about compatibility of versions ?

Comment: Probably not the issue, you don't specify the version in your pom, which means it takes the versions maintained by spring, i.e. https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.7.2/spring-boot-dependencies-2.7.2.pom

Comment: @zapl can you tell me why am I getting this in console ?

Comment: No :) You can try to replace `spring-aop` with `spring-boot-starter-aop` since that also manages the version it needs. hibernate is probably also not required as direct dependency if you use https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jpa Maybe try a different version of spring-boot, 2.7.3 should be the latest

Comment: Can you please paste the first few lines of the stack trace? Besides that, it will be good if you format your code for better reading.

Comment: For starters your dependencies are a bit of a mess, clean those up first. Remove the jackson dependency (included in the web stuff), remove the `spring-security` dependency (already in the `spring-boot-starter-security`). Remove the hibernate dependencies and remaining `spring-*` dependencies and add `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` instead. Also do you really need `spring-boot-starter-web-services` (that is for SOAP based web services!) or did you want the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency to start. Please add the **full stacktrace** (edit the question not as comment)

Comment: @Leonardo Emmanuel de Azevedo at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
 at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
 at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]